# Search text between symbol

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, postgresql-8.4

I have this text (taken from concatenated field row)

`Astronomic Event 2013/1434H - Aceh ....`

How do We search it by `2013` or `1434h` keywords?

I have tried below code but it resulting no row.

`to_tsvector` result:

`'2013/1434h':8,12 'aceh':1 'bin.....`

Sample Case:

```
WITH sample_table as
  (SELECT to_tsvector('Astronomic Event 2013/1434H - Aceh') sample_content)

SELECT *
    FROM sample_table, to_tsquery('2013') q
WHERE sample_content @@ q
```

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Please include the following information in your question.  PostgreSQL version you are using.  Based on your tags, it appears to be an older, unsupported version.  Good job on listing what you've tried so far, but also, please clearly state what you want the result to be.

Comment: I don't see how the query shown in the question could run without error, much less guess what was intended.

Comment: please include the string you're feeding to_tsquery.

Comment: @FuzzyChef See edit, the string is search keyword,

Comment: @kgrittn See edit, i have added some sample case.

Answer (score 1):

> How do We search it by 2013 or 1434h keywords?

It seems like you want to replace:

```
to_tsquery('1434h') q
```

with:

```
to_tsquery('1434h | 2013') q
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-textsearch.html

Side note: the `to_tsquery()` syntax is extremely capricious. It doesn't allow for much if any fantasy, and many of the assumptions in Postgres are everything but end-user friendly.

More often than not, you'll be better off using `plainto_tsquery()`, which allows any amount of garbage to be thrown at it. Thus, consider pre-processing the string before issuing the query. For instance, you could split the string, and `OR` the original parts together:

```
where sc.text_index @@ (plainto_tsquery('1434h') || plainto_tsquery('2013'))
```

Doing so will make your code a bit more complex, but it won't rely on your users needing to understand that (contrary to what they're accustomed to in Google) they should enter `'quick & brown & fox & jumps & lazy & dog'` instead of plain `'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'`.

---

Edit: I ended up actually trying your sample query, and it seems you're actually running into a parser issue:

```
# SELECT alias, description, token FROM ts_debug('Astronomic Event 2013/1434H - Aceh');
   alias   |    description    |   token    
-----------+-------------------+------------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII   | Astronomic
 blank     | Space symbols     |  
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII   | Event
 blank     | Space symbols     |  
 file      | File or path name | 2013/1434H
 blank     | Space symbols     |  
 blank     | Space symbols     | - 
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII   | Aceh
(8 rows)
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-parsers.html

It looks like you might need to write (or find) and configure an app-specific parser. Having never done this personally, the best I can do is to highlight that Postgres allows this and includes a sample:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/test-parser.html

Alternatively, change your tsvector-related trigger so that it matches e.g. `\d{4}/\d+[a-zA-Z]` or whatever seems most appropriate, and adds spaces accordingly, before converting it to a tsvector. Something as simple as the following might do the trick if you never need to store file names:

```
SELECT alias, description, token
FROM ts_debug(replace('Astronomic Event 2013/1434H - Aceh', '/', ' / '));
```

Comment: Hi @Denis, see edit, i have added a sample case, i have changed `to_tsquery` to `plainto_tsquery` but it still doesn't work.